# Confusing .where query result using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run a simple fetch using ActiveRecord and I'm confused by the result. This is the code I'm trying to run

```
c = Child.where("name LIKE ?", "%John D%")
```

I have a Child model and a corresponding table in my database. There is a record for "John Doe" in the database that outputs as being found in the rails console. However, when I execute

```
c.name
```

It outputs

```
=> "Child"
```

instead of

```
=> "John Doe"
```

If I run

```
c = Child.find_by_name("John Doe")
```

everything works fine. I'm sure there is an obvious solution here, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` returns an [ActiveRecord Relation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). If you do a `c.class` that will give you `ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Child`. To get an actual object you can just do:

```
c = Child.where("name LIKE ?", "%John D%").first
```

Note that will be `nil` if there are no results for the query.

Comment: This works. You can also use `c = Child.where("name LIKE ?", "%John D%").all` to get an Array of all matching results

Comment: Yup! There are lots of things you can do with the results :).